# cant retrieve ole object with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image, blob

I'm trying to retrieve an image from my database but somehow it seems to go wrong with the SQL

This is the code:

```
 public partial class producten : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int artikelnummer = 1;
        //Connect
        string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
        Source=C:\Users\jeroen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\producten
              \producten\App_Data\Bimsports.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);


        //Execute
        string sql = "SELECT Merk, Maat, Omschrijving, Kleur, Prijs, BTW, 
                Categorie.Categorie, foto FROM Artikel INNER JOIN Categorie ON 
                Artikel.Categorie = Categorie.Categorienummer WHERE Artikelnummer =?";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Artikelnummer", artikelnummer);
        //Read
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lbl_merk.Text = reader["Merk"].ToString();
                lbl_maat.Text = reader["Maat"].ToString();
                lbl_omschrijving.Text = reader["Omschrijving"].ToString();
                lbl_kleur.Text = reader["Kleur"].ToString();
                lbl_prijs.Text = reader["Prijs"].ToString();
                lbl_btw.Text = reader["BTW"].ToString();
                lbl_categorie.Text = reader["Categorie"].ToString();
                byte[] image = (byte[])(reader["foto"]);
                if (image == null)
                    img_nikeshirt.ImageUrl = null;
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(image);
                    img_nikeshirt.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(image);
                }
            }   

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_merk.Text = "er ging iets fout bij de verbinding" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

`foto` is the ole `object(jpg)`.

If I execute it like this it won't work. If I delete `foto` there's nothing wrong.
is something wrong with the object? I can open it in access.
is there something special to do with an ole object?

Comment: "It won't work".  That's about as descriptive as going to the doctor and saying "I hurt".

Answer (score 0):

First of all as you said a picture is an object and you are trying to access a [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) as a string and that's why it is crashing. Try to look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand how. I'm copying the example from the MSDN:

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT pub_id, logo FROM pub_info", connection);

// Writes the BLOB to a file (*.bmp).
FileStream stream;                          
// Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.
BinaryWriter writer;                        

// Size of the BLOB buffer.
int bufferSize = 100;                   
// The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];  
// The bytes returned from GetBytes.
long retval;                            
// The starting position in the BLOB output.
long startIndex = 0;                    

// The publisher id to use in the file name.
string pubID = "";                     

// Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

while (reader.Read())
{
  // Get the publisher id, which must occur before getting the logo.
  pubID = reader.GetString(0);  

  // Create a file to hold the output.
  stream = new FileStream(
    "logo" + pubID + ".bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
  writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

  // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.
  startIndex = 0;

  // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
  retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

  // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
  while (retval == bufferSize)
  {
    writer.Write(outByte);
    writer.Flush();

    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
    startIndex += bufferSize;
    retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
  }

  // Write the remaining buffer.
  writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
  writer.Flush();

  // Close the output file.
  writer.Close();
  stream.Close();
}

// Close the reader and the connection.
reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: i have edited my code (look above) i cant see to find it to work. if i execute it error is "something went wrong with the connection foto. in visual studio there are no errors. am i getting close?

Comment: Yes. You're totally out of sight. If you want to store the Image to Base64 in Access you can do that if you specify the field as "Memo" if you specify the field as a Ole Object you will need to read the byte[] as shown in the example above. Then store into a temp file and then specify the Url with Map.Path().

If you want to retrieve the image directly from the DataBase I recommend to use a GridView. Here is an example:http://odetocode.com/Articles/172.aspx

Comment: i got it to work through another way. look at my other question i answered it myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785322/retrieving-image-from-database-with-handler